# Array sin números repetidos

Tags: java

Alguien me colabora con un código en java de crear un vector de tamaño `n` y validar que no se ingresen números repetidos.

Esto es lo que llevo pero no sé como seguir:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SinRepetir {
     Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
     private int[] vec;

    public void LlenarVector(){
        int i,N;
        System.out.print("Ingrese el tamaño del vector:");
        N=sc.nextInt();
        vec = new int[N];
        for(i=0;i<N;i++){
            System.out.print("Ingrese un numero entero:");
            vec[i]=sc.nextInt();
            int k=i+1;
            if(vec[k]=vec[i]){

            }

        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola puedes usar un Hashset para determinar si el numero ya fue insertado (es optimo porque tiene una complejidad algorítmica de 1), por ejemplo

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int i,n;
    System.out.println("Ingrese el tamaño del vector:");
    n=sc.nextInt();
    HashSet<Integer> hashSet = new HashSet<>(n);
    for(i=0;i<n;){
        System.out.println("Ingrese un numero entero:");
        int number =sc.nextInt();
        if(hashSet.add(number)){
            i++;
        }else{
            System.out.println("el numero "+number+" ya se agrego");
        }

    }
    Integer array[] = new Integer[n];
    array = hashSet.toArray(array);

    System.out.println("el array ingresado fue "+ Arrays.toString(array));
    }
}
```

Comment: no puede ser con funciones de java, es por medio de la logica

Comment: ¿Sería mucho pedir que agregues lo que significa "HashSet"?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba el siguiente código:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SinRepetir {

    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    static int[] vec;
    static int i, N, auxiliar;

    /**
     *
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.print("Ingrese el tamaño del vector:");

        N = sc.nextInt();
        vec = new int[N];
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            System.out.print("Ingrese un numero entero:");
            auxiliar = sc.nextInt();
            boolean check = true;
            for (int l = 0; l < vec.length && check; l++) {
                if (vec[l] == auxiliar) {
                    check = false;
                }
            }

            if (check) {
                vec[i] = auxiliar;
            }else{
                System.out.print("El numero: " + auxiliar + ya guardado en el array, introduzca otro numero.");
                i--;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Me he centrado en que funcione, puedes limpiar el código para que sea más legible y "bonito".

Comment: No hace nada, deja ingresar datos repetidos

Comment: No lo ingresa, solo te vuelve a preguntar en caso de que ya exista. Prueba a hacer un array de 2 de longitud, te va a pedir un numero hasta que no ingreses un numero sin repetir, si quieres te edito para que te muestre algo como "numero repetido"

Comment: Ya lo he editado, pruebalo y me dices.

Comment: Muchas gracias pero debo mostrarlo :(

Comment: Modificado para que muestre el número repetido.

Answer (score 0):

Lo he hecho en base a lógica solamente.

**Código:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SO {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int[] vector;

        System.out.print("Ingrese el tamaño del vector: ");
        int tamano = sc.nextInt();

        vector = new int[tamano];

        for (int i = 0; i < tamano; i++) {

            System.out.print("[" + i + "] Ingrese un numero entero: ");
            vector[i] = sc.nextInt();

            if (i > 0) { // Obviar la primera iteración

                // Mientras el número sea repetido, preguntar por otro
                while (validar(vector, i, vector[i])) {
                    System.out.print("Aviso!, " + vector[i] + " está repetido, ingrese otro: ");
                    vector[i] = sc.nextInt();
                }
            }

        }

        // Cerrar Scanner
        sc.close();
    }

    /**
     * Validar que "numero" no exista en el vector
     * @param vector    Vector tipo int[]
     * @param posicion  Posicion del "numero" dentro del for en el main
     * @param numero    Numero a validar
     * @return          Retorna un booleano. True si está repetido o False si no lo está
     */
    public static boolean validar(int[] vector, int posicion, int numero) {
        boolean esRepetido = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < vector.length; i++) {

            if (i != posicion && vector[i] == numero) {
                // Numero repetido
                esRepetido = true;
            }
        }
        return esRepetido;
    }
}
```

**Resultado:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero haberte ayudado, saludos!.

Comment: Me muestra un error en el while en la palabra validar. podrias editarlo Gracias

Comment: @EmmanuelArenillaMendoza acabo de probarlo nuevamente y no recibo ningún error. Recuerda que el método validar es `public static boolean`. La palabra `static` es importante para que el método pueda ser llamado desde el `main`. Si por algún otro motivo sigues teniendo problemas, puedes mover el método a otro sitio o puedes introducirlo dentro del `main`. Yo por mi lado no recibo ningún error.

Answer (score 0):

para que no se repita la logica es esta, ordenas el arreglo luego comparas el primer elemento con el siguiente y si es diferente lo guardas hasta el tamaño del arreglo-1 y despues solo colocas el ultimo numero que falta en arreglo.length -1 seria algo asi:

```
public static int[] sinRepetir(int[]a){
   Arrays.sort(a);
   int len = a.length;
   int j = 0;
   for(int i=0;i<len-1;i++){
       if(a[i]!=a[i+1]){
          a[j++] = a[i];
       }
   }
   a[j++] = a[len-1];
   int [] c = new int[j];
   for(int k = 0;k<j;k++){
   c[k] = a[k];
   }
   return c;
   }
```

[acá una explicación](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NjpmeQ--Lj4&t=248s)